# Understanding Analytic Signals

Tags: discrete-signals, analytic-signal

I know that a function $f_a\in \text{L}^2(\mathrm{R})$ is an [*analytic signal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal) if its Fourier transform is 0 for negative frequencies, i.e.

$$ \hat{f_a}(\omega)=0$ if $\omega<0 $$

We can characterize an analytic function by its real part $f = \text{Re}[f_a]$, and the Fourier transform of this function is

$$ \hat{f_a}(\omega)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
2\hat{f}(\omega) & \text{if }\omega\geq0 \\ 
0 & \text{if }\omega<0
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Now if we have a discrete signal $f[n]$ of size $N$, we can also compute $f_a[n]$ by setting the negative frequency components of its discrete Fourier transform to 0.

Now why is it that if we want $\text{Re}[f_a]=f$, then we must have:

$$ \hat{f_a}[k]=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\hat{f}[k] && \text{if }k=0,N/2\\   
2\hat{f}[k] && \text{if }0<k<N/2\\ 
0 && \text{if } N/2<k<N
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Could that be explained?

Comment: I thought a function was analytic on the line or plane if it can be approximated by a convergent series.

Comment: @Tom Kealy: The OP confuses _analytic functions_ and _analytic signals_.

Comment: @chirlu I mentioned that in my answer below.

Comment: Your characterization of an analytic signal in the continuous-frequency domain is incorrect. [See Wikipedia's definition.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're asking, but I think you want to know why the DFT of a signal has extra conditions for it to real.

For the continuous case: the 2 is there because we need a function to be symmetric to have a real Fourier transform.

In the discrete case, the DFT obey the symmtery:

$$
X_{N-k} = X_{-k} = X_k^* 
$$
i.e. conjugate symmetry (half the values are just complex conjugates of the other half). Thus $X_0$ and $X_{N/2}$ are real numbers whilst the remainder of the DFT is specified by $N/2-1$ complex numbers (hence the 2 in the second line).

[Also, the answers to this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5696/is-a-function-analytical-on-c-iff-its-fourier-transform-vanishes-for-negative-fr)

offer counterexamples to your first statement - that analytic functions have vanishing negative frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

Analytic signals to get a but more tricky in the discrete domain because of the periodicity in the time domain and the circular nature of the convolution. This article treats that fairly well http://www.andrewduncan.ws/air/

Comment: The article has moved: [The Analytic Impulse](http://andrewduncan.net/air/). Would you know of a pdf ?

Comment: The link still works for me. If not, you can try http://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=5035